Function orthogonal to the square of any eigenfunction
Suppose you are given a function $V(x)$ that is even in all its variables such that
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^n}V(x)|u_j(x)|^2dx = 0,
$$
for all $j = 1,2,...$, where $u_j(x)$ is the $j^{th}$ eigenfunction of the $n$-dimensional anisotropic harmonic oscillator. This means that each eigenfunction $u_j(x)$ can be written as a product of eigenfunctions of $1$-dimensional harmonic oscillators. How can I rigorously show that V(x) must be identically $0$?
Assume for simplicity that the (self-adjoint) Hamiltonian of the anisotropic Harmonic oscillator is given by
$$
-\cfrac{1}{2}\Delta +\cfrac{1}{2}\sum_{j = 1}^n\omega_j^2x_j^2.
$$
Many thanks for the help :)
Edit: As pointed out by @DavidGao, the assumption on the parity of V(x) is needed, otherwise the statement is false.

@whpowell96 Thank you for your suggestion. I updated the question and included the self-adjoint PDE operator.  Do you mind explaining some of the steps? I would highly appreciate it!

@whpowell96 Yes, I am able to use this fact.

@whpowell96 This does not simply follow from being a complete orthogonal basis because the OP’s formula uses $|u_j(x)|^2$ instead of $u_j(x)$. One example would be on the unit circle, $e^{inx}$ for $n \in \mathbb{Z}$ form an ONB but their absolute values squared are all constant $1$. A real-valued example would be $\sin(nx)$ for $n \geq 1$ and $\cos(nx)$ for $n \geq 0$ on $[-\pi, \pi]$, which together form an ONB, but their squares are all even functions, so all odd functions are orthogonal to all their squares.

(A small correction to my last comment: sines and cosines in the Fourier series are not an ONB, just a complete orthogonal basis without additional normalization. But this doesn’t affect my point.) In fact, isn’t this squaring already a problem here? 1-d harmonic oscillator has as its eigenfunctions Gaussian density function multiplied by either even or odd polynomials. So their squares are all even functions, and any odd function would be orthogonal to all their squares. Multidimensional versions have the same issue. Any $V$ that is odd in all its coordinates is a counterexample.

If $V(x) u_j(x)\in \mathcal L^2(\mathbb R^n)$, it must be orthogonal to all $u$.   So it remains to show, that $V=0$ in $\mathcal(L^1, e^{- |\mathbf x}|^2)^*$

@RolandF What do you mean? $V(x)u_j(x)$ is only orthogonal to $u_j$, not any other $u$. The OP only wrote $V(x)|u_j(x)|^2$ integrates to $0$ for all $j$, not $\overline{u_i(x)}V(x)u_j(x)$ integrates to $0$ for all $i, j$.

I misread the integrand David. Thanks for pointing that out. I agree with your parity argument.

If you want $\langle u_i, V u_i\rangle \ = \ 0 $ , $V u $ has to be orthogonal to $u$

@RolandF $Vu_i$ is certainly orthogonal to $u_i$. There’s no reason it has to be orthogonal to $u_j$ for any $j \neq i$. I’m not sure what you even meant by “$Vu$ has to be orthogonal to $u$” - what is $u$ referring to, in any case? There are only $u_i$ for each $i$.

In order to determine V, it has to have a domain as a´symmetric operator or its a distribution. A selfadjoint extension of V(x) as a bounded symmeric operator, that maps any vector in Hilbert space to its orthogonal complement has a standard implementation as a shift plus permutations. But the shift cannot be represented by an multiplication operator, as far as I see.

@DavidGao Thank you for pointing this out. I have added this constraint on V(x) that it is even in each argument xj. I didn’t know that this property was crucial to prove the statement.

@RolandF I don't understand what you mean. Why would $V$ define a bounded operator?

@RolandF That’s basically nonsense. Sending all $u_i$ to its orthogonal complement doesn’t mean it sends all vectors to their orthogonal complements. The latter is simply impossible on a complex Hilbert space, unless the operator is the zero operator, which can be proved using the complex version of the polarization identity. The former, however, is easy to arrange, even using a multiplication operator. Indeed, in line with my previous comment, multiplication by $x$ is such an operator on $L^2[-\pi, \pi]$ - it sends all sines and cosines in the Fourier series to their orthogonal complements.

@RolandF Also, the middle sentence of your comment, “[a] selfadjoint extension of $V(x)$ as a bounded [symmetric] operator, that maps any vector in Hilbert space to its orthogonal complement has a standard implementation as a shift plus permutations”, is nonsensical. Even on a real Hilbert space, a symmetric operator sending all vectors to their orthogonal complements is zero. (And on a complex Hilbert space, this is true without even assuming the operator is self-adjoint.) You seem to either have a fundamental misunderstanding of self-adjoint operators, or of shift operators, or both.

You probably never heard about creation and annihilation operators or the limit of possible potential disturbing the oscillator.

@Sabiske At least if $V$ is in $L^2$ and compactly supported (on compact essential support $K$), this is now true. A proof sketch is as follows: use induction to prove that, in the 1-d case, $|u_j|^2$ span all even polynomials multiplied by the square of a Gaussian density function. Using standard approximation techniques - approximate $\bar{V}$ by even continuous functions supported on $K$, then approximate these even continuous functions (divided by the square of the Gaussian density) by even polynomials using Stone-Weierstrass - one can show that…

@Sabiske … there is a sequence in the span of $|u_j|^2$ that converges to $\bar{V}$ in $L^2(K)$. Using $L^2(\mathbb{R}^n) = L^2(\mathbb{R})^{\otimes n}$, one can then extend this to higher-dimensional cases. Now, using this, one conclude that if $V$ is in $L^2$, compactly supported, even, and orthogonal to all $|u_j|^2$, it must be $0$. I think a more careful argument along these lines should reduce the assumptions of in $L^2$ and compactly supported to locally in $L^2$, though I haven’t figured out a precise argument.

@RolandF I’m not sure what you’re on about now. Creation and annihilation operators are adjoints of each other. Neither are self-adjoint. (Nor do they map all vectors to their orthogonal complements - they only map eigenstates of the Hamiltonian to their orthogonal complements. Say, if $ae_0 = \alpha e_1$ and $ae_1 = \beta e_2$ where $e_0$ is the vacuum state, $e_1$, $e_2$ the first and second excited states, respectively, and $\alpha$, $\beta$ some scalars, then $a(e_0 + e_1) = \alpha e_1 + \beta e_2$ is not orthogonal to $e_0 + e_1$.)

@DavidGao Many thanks for your help! I truly appreciate it! I will try to do it for the 1-d case first and go from there!

@Sabiske I wrote an answer which simplifies the argument and proves the result for most “reasonable” $V$. You can follow the argument there.

@David: In the Hilbert space with the Hermite basis $H_n$ and ground state measure $e^{-x^2}$ the operators $$a_{\pm}=x\pm \partial_x$$ are the so called ladder operators, $x$ is their sum and any $V(x)$  is a formal series in these spectral shift operators.  Conclusion about V=0 is more of the kind V does not exist.  Consider the opposite case: $p^2$ and $x^2$ have very different domains, their sum again another maximal domain: its  is a symmetrized product of  $a_{\pm} $. In mathematical physics it's convenient to study the classic Reed/Simon before reasoning about existence of operators

@RolandF I know what ladder operators are. I’m asking you a simple question: which operator are you claiming is self-adjoint and, to quote yourself, “maps any vector in Hilbert space to its orthogonal complement”. Because ladder operators, in case you’re not aware, are not self-adjoint (nor do they send every vector to their orthogonal complement, for that matter).

Here is an argument that’s similar in ideas to my comments, and that proves the result for a large class of $V$: Let $\psi$ be the Gaussian density function appearing in all $u_j$. (Recall that $u_j$ are all multi-dimensional Hermite polynomials multiplied by a fixed Gaussian density function that depends only on $\omega$’s and not on $j$.) Then the result is true for all $V$ for which it is known that $V(x)\psi(x) \in L^2$. (This includes, for example, all $V \in L^\infty$ and all continuous $V$ whose growths are bounded by some polynomials.) Note that in the 1-d case, $u_j$ is $\psi$ multiplied with a polynomial of order $j$. From this, it is not hard to conclude, by induction, that that the span of $|u_j|^2$ is all even polynomials multiplies by $\psi^2$. Using the 1-d result, it is straightforward to conclude that the same holds for higher-dimensional cases, i.e., the span of $|u_j|^2$ is always all polynomials even in all variables multiplied by $\psi^2$. Thus, $\langle u_j, V\psi \rangle = \int V(x)p(x)\psi^2(x) \, dx$ equals zero for any $u_j(x) = p(x)\psi(x)$ which is even in all variables, as in those cases $p(x)$ are even polynomials. Since $V(x)$ is assumed even, $V(x)\psi(x)$ is even as well. All other $u_j$ are odd in at least one variable, so we obtain $\langle u_j, V\psi \rangle = 0$ for all $j$. Since $V(x)\psi(x)$ is assumed to be in $L^2$, we have $V(x)\psi(x) \equiv 0$. As $\psi(x) > 0$ for all $x$, we conclude that $V = 0$.
